# Plotting multiple items in a list using ggplot in R

Tags: r, list, ggplot2

I have a list of data frames that are all of the same structure, and I want to plot information from all of these data frames on the same diagram in R using ggplot, like when facet_wrap is used to show multiple panels on a single image, but am having trouble. below I have created a reproducible example.

```
library(ggplot)

#Designating 3 datasets:

data_1 <- mtcars
data_2 <- mtcars
data_3 <- mtcars


#Making them into a list:

mylist <- list(data_1, data_2, data_3)


#What things should look like, with facet_wrap being by "dataset", and thus a panel for each of the
#three datasets presented. 

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~Species)
```

But instead, when I run the following, I get an error saying that the data must be presented as a dataframe, not a list:

```
ggplot(mylist, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~.x)
```

Does anyone know the best way to use ggplot to plot from a list like this? Do you have to somehow wrap ggplot within lapply()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to bind your dataframes by row using e.g. `dplyr::bind_rows`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

data_1 <- mtcars
data_2 <- mtcars
data_3 <- mtcars

mylist <- list(data_1, data_2, data_3) |> 
  dplyr::bind_rows(.id = "id")

ggplot(mylist, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~id)
```

[image]